# javascript how to get cookie value with a leading dot on domain

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

A cookie "test" created by PHP appears in my console with a dot: `.mydomain.com`. How do I get its value?

```
    setcookie('test', $value, time()+(100 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', 'mydomain.com', true, true);
```

I've tried a lot of scripts found here but none of them work:

```
    function getCookie1(name) {
        function escape(s) { return s.replace(/([.*+?\^$(){}|\[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1'); }
        var match = document.cookie.match(RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)' + escape(name) + '=([^;]*)'));
        return match ? match[1] : null;
    }
    console.log('cookie 1 = '+getCookie1('test'))

    function getCookie2(name) {
          const regex = new RegExp(`(^| )${name}=([^;]+)`)
          const match = document.cookie.match(regex)
          if (match) {
            return match[2]
          }
       }
    console.log('cookie 2 = '+getCookie2('test'))

    function getCookie3(name) {
      let cookie = {};
      document.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(el) {
        let split = el.split('=');
        cookie[split[0].trim()] = split.slice(1).join("=");
      })
      return cookie[name];
    }
    console.log('cookie 3 = '+getCookie3('test'))

    function getCookie4(name){
      document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + name + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)')?.pop() || ''
    }
    console.log('cookie 4 = '+getCookie4('test'))

    function getCookie5(name) {
        if(document.cookie.length>0) {
            start=document.cookie.indexOf(name+"=");
            pos = start+name.length+1;
            if(start!=0) {
                start=document.cookie.indexOf("; "+name+"=");
                pos = start+name.length+3;
            }
            if(start!=-1) { 
                start=pos;
                end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",start);
                if(end==-1) {
                    end=document.cookie.length;
                }
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(start,end));
            } 
        }
        return '';
    }
    console.log('cookie 5 = '+getCookie5('test'))
```

Is it possible to recover it as it is, or do I have to rewrite PHP's setcookie differently?

Comment: You have set the `$httponly` parameter to true in your setcookie call, which means that cookie is explicitly _not_ available to client-side scripting languages.

Comment: `setcookie('test', $value, time()+(100 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', 'mydomain.com', true, false);`?

Comment: Thanks, it works. Sorry for my low PHP level ...